# solving nonlinear equations

Tags: matlab, equation, equation-solving

I want to solve two nonlinear equations in MATLAB so i did the following:

part of my script

```
c=[A\u;A\v];
% parts of code are omitted.
x0=[1;1];
sol= fsolve(@myfunc,x0);
```

the `myfunc` function is as follows

```
function F = myfunc(x)

  F=[ x(1)*c(1)+x(2)*c(2)+x(1)*x(2)*c(3)+c(4)-ii;

     x(1)*c(5)+x(2)*c(6)+x(1)*x(2)*c(7)+c(8)-jj];

end
```

i have two unknowns `x(1)` and `x(2)`

my question is How to pass a values(`c`,`ii`,`jj`) to `myfunc` in every time i call it?

or how to overcome this error `Undefined function or method 'c' for input arguments of type 'double'.`

thanks

Comment: my question is clear or not?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: The previous answer was bogus and not contributing at all. Hence has been deleted. Here is the right way.

In your main code create a vector of the coefficients `c,ii,jj` and a dummy function handle `f_d`

```
coeffs = [c,ii,jj];
f_d = @(x0) myfunc(x0,coeffs);      % f_d considers x0 as variables
sol = fsolve(f_d,x0);
```

Make your function `myfunc` capable of taking in 2 variables, `x0` and `coeffs`

```
function F = myfunc(x, coeffs)
c = coeffs(1:end-2);
ii = coeffs(end-1);
jj = coeffs(end);

F(1) = x(1)*c(1)+x(2)*c(2)+x(1)*x(2)*c(3)+c(4)-ii;
F(2) = x(1)*c(5)+x(2)*c(6)+x(1)*x(2)*c(7)+c(8)-jj;
```

I think that should solve for x0(1) and x0(2).

Edit: Thank you Eitan_T. Changes have been made above.

Comment: this means that i solve for 12 variable! which is wrong, i only have two unknowns. any way thanks for your answer

Comment: I was too hasty in writing that. Let me write the code out properly and post it. I know you are saying that 2 equations for 12 variables is inconsistent. Let me write it again.

Comment: @Apteronotus `x0` is defined outside `myfunc`. Inside `myfunc` that should be `x`.

Comment: By the way, if `x` and `c` are vectors, you can use a scalar product instead of explicitly writing that sum: `F(1) =  x * c(1:4) - coeffs(end - 1);` and `F(2) = x * c(5:8) - coeffs(end);`. However, you should pay attention to vector dimensions and transpose if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative option, that I prefer, if a function handle is not what you are looking for.

Say I have this function:

```
function y = i_have_a_root( x, a )
    y = a*x^2;
end
```

You can pass in your initial guess for `x` and a value for `a` by just calling `fsolve` like so:

```
a = 5;
x0 = 0;
root = fsolve('i_have_a_root',x0,[],a);
```

Note: The `[]` is reserved for `fsolve` options, which you probably want to use. See the second call to `fsolve` in the documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html) for information on the `options` argument.